# Base table or view not found: when loading product

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm trying to load a product since upgrading a sample installation to Magento 1.9.3.4 and facing this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_mage1x.catalog_product_entity_catalog_' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_catalog_` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) ORDER BY `store_id` ASC
```

The code I used is

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load(877);
```

I've checked some other databases on other installations that I've never faced an issue and it seems there isn't a table named `catalog_product_entity_catalog_` there either.

The product is from the magento sample data
[image]

I can't find any info regarding this issue online.

Here's the full exception log

```
2017-07-18T14:04:52+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_mage1x.catalog_product_entity_catalog_' doesn't exist' in /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `attr_ta...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `attr_ta...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(996): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(959): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_loadModelAttributes(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 877, NULL)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 877, NULL)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/community/domain/StockManager/Helper/Data.php(41): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(877)
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/community/domain/StockManager/controllers/LabelController.php(59): domain_StockManager_Helper_Data->getProductsBySku('wbk002c')
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): domain_StockManager_LabelController->getProductsBySkuAction()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('getProductsBySk...')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_mage1x.catalog_product_entity_catalog_' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_catalog_` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `attr_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '13' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '877') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) ORDER BY `store_id` ASC' in /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `attr_ta...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `attr_ta...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(996): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(959): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_loadModelAttributes(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 877, NULL)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 877, NULL)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/community/domain/StockManager/Helper/Data.php(41): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(877)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/community/domain/StockManager/controllers/LabelController.php(59): domain_StockManager_Helper_Data->getProductsBySku('wbk002c')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): domain_StockManager_LabelController->getProductsBySkuAction()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('getProductsBySk...')
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/dev.domain.gr/private/magento/1x/default/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

I tried disabling all 3rd party modules and still the same  adding my code to footer.phtml in rwd theme.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of busting my head, it ended up being a product attribute that wasn't created or migrated correctly. After deleting it the problem disappeared